# Create more than 1 clone of an app

Tags: applications

I know that there are apps like **2face** that can clone an app, but they can just create a single clone. Is there another application that can clone an app more than once? Let's say 5-10 clones in the same device.

Note: I have also tried **Parallel Space** but it cannot clone **Entrust ST** which I am trying to clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lucky Patcher . But know that it doesn't work for all apps. And also cloning an app twice will take twice the space. If you are a root user I will recommend you to use titanium backup and create multiple profiles for the app. It even had a stylish widget with the active profile name so that you can switch to different profiles with just one tap. Adding multiple profiles to an app is just like cloning but one app several app data in separate partition.
Titanum backup requires root. Very low ram and battery  consumption